# How to connect to a nodejs express server through proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, socket.io

We have a nodejs http server running on port 8090 on IP 182.74.215.86 and we want to connect to this server via proxy 104.236.147.107:56220.

Our client code is

```html
 this.socket = require('socket.io-client').connect(url, 
 {
  // This line ensures that each client connection will have different client.id
  'force new connection': true,
 });

 this.socket.once('connect', function() 
 {
 })
 .on('disconnect', function() 
 {
 })
 .on('error', function(e) 
 {
  console.error("(storetalk.js) ASL: Unable to connect to garuda gateway:- " + e);
 });
```

Comment: Have you consider using nginx?

Comment: We have a nodejs http server running on AWS on port 8090 and we have a windows desktop client connected to this server via socket.io-client. Now the problem is the client is not working when it is on a LAN a connected to a proxy server

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using NGinx.

Installed nginx on my red hat server on ip 192.168.10.238
 My node application server is running on same ip on port 8090
 configured nginx to listen on 8020 and configured it with to support socket.io
 my nodejs client is connected to application server via this nginx proxy

Below is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf configuration file

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events 
{
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http 
{
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade 
    {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server 
    {
        listen 8020;

        location / 
        {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass  http://192.168.10.238:8090;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            }
    }
}
```